# Method to return records true false or all

Tags: c#, linq, methods

Is there a better way to write the method below? I want to return content based on a `bool` variable `IsPublished`.

When `IsPublished` is `null` I want to return entries that are both `true` and `false`.

```
public IList<Content> GetContent(bool? IsPublished)
{
    if (IsPublished != null)
    {
        return _UoW.Content.All.Where(c => c.IsPublished == IsPublished).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return _UoW.Content.All.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: somthing like `_UoW.Content.All.Where(c=> !IsPublished.HasValue || c.IsPublished == IsPublished.Value).ToList();`

Comment: Better in what respect?  Note that you have a typo - your `Where` clause should be `==`, not `=`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe just so i dont have to use the if statement - maybe hesam has got it solved?

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr that's just shorter; it would check `IsPublished` each time, unnecessarily (correct me if I'm wrong; maybe it optimizes the code because it knows the variable won't change each time the lambda runs?) I would just convert it to a ternary.

Comment: As @FurkanKambay says, given that when it's null you don't want to run a filter at all, I'd say it's fine as it is (or as a ternary as suggested) - whether the redundant `Where` would get optimised away in the `null` case or not, the intent is then clearer - no filtering when `null`.

Comment: yes it would check IsPublished each time, I thought you meant shorter, my bad

Comment: Personally, I would stick to the if statement. I almost always value readability over brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to be brief, you don't need `{` `}` blocks for single statement `if` `else` bodies.

But perhaps a single return point is what you are looking for:

```
public IList<Content> GetContent(bool? IsPublished) {
    var ans = _UoW.Content.All;
    if (IsPublished.HasValue)
        ans = ans.Where(c => c.IsPublished == IsPublished);

    return ans.ToList();
}
```

(Assuming the type of `All` is compatible with the return type of `Where`. If not, you can change the assignment to be `var ans = _UoW.Content.All.Where(c => true)`.)

Comment: I could have picked any of the answers to be honest, but this one is just that little more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If by better, you mean shorter, operator `?` can be the solution. Also, there is no point using filter when the `isPublished == null`. Please refer to Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) for `?` operator.

```
public IList<Content> GetContent(bool? IsPublished)
{
    return isPublished != null ? _UoW.Content.All.Where(c=>c.IsPublished== IsPublished).ToList() : _UoW.Content.All.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as efficient, but *is* compact:

```
public IList<Content> GetContent(bool? IsPublished)
    => _UoW.Content.All.Where(c => !IsPublished.HasValue || c.IsPublished == IsPublished).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null coalesce operator `??` and filter on `x.IsPublished == (v ?? x.IsPublished)`

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsPublished { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<A> Filter(IEnumerable<A> items, Nullable<bool> v)
{
    return items.Where(x => x.IsPublished == (v ?? x.IsPublished)).ToList();
}

var listy = new List<A>();
listy.Add(new A() { Id=1, IsPublished=null });
listy.Add(new A() { Id=2, IsPublished=true });
listy.Add(new A() { Id=3, IsPublished=false });
listy.Add(new A() { Id=4, IsPublished=null });
listy.Add(new A() { Id=5, IsPublished=true });
listy.Add(new A() { Id=6, IsPublished=false });
```

C# interactive console demo:

```
> Filter(listy, null)
List<Submission#0.A>(6) { Submission#0.A { Id=1, IsPublished=null }, Submission#0.A { Id=2, IsPublished=true }, Submission#0.A { Id=3, IsPublished=false }, Submission#0.A { Id=4, IsPublished=null }, Submission#0.A { Id=5, IsPublished=true }, Submission#0.A { Id=6, IsPublished=false } }
> Filter(listy, true)
List<Submission#0.A>(2) { Submission#0.A { Id=2, IsPublished=true }, Submission#0.A { Id=5, IsPublished=true } }
> Filter(listy, false)
List<Submission#0.A>(2) { Submission#0.A { Id=3, IsPublished=false }, Submission#0.A { Id=6, IsPublished=false } }
```

(The class above is `A` instead of `Content` and the method is `Filter` instead of `GetContent`)